Options menu doesn't show when running the app + the icons aren't showing in the xml
I'm trying to make my app show the 3-dots menu button up top which will result in a button that when clicked will show the options described in menu.xml(yes I created it in a menu folder with a menu resource file)
MainActivity:
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        //I have also tried return true
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.itemOne:
                Toast.makeText(this, "settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

            case R.id.itemTwo:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

menu.xml:
I have tried with the parts at the top and without but it didn't work either way
also it doesnt show the icons
What is shown in the xml, the icons aren't visible for some reason
what I want it to show when it is being run
what is shown when I run the app and in main activity(don't mind the settings button above and the logout at the bottom they will be removed)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemOne"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_settings_24"
        android:title="Settings" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemTwo"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_logout_24"
        android:title="Logout" />
</menu>

I have honestly tried everything in this world, I have gone through all previous somewhat related threads they all gave answers which I have implemented both in menu.xml and in MainActivity, I just dont understand why it doesnt work or what should I search to make something like this work.
Thanks!!!

"I have honestly tried everything in this world" - did you try adding a Toolbar to your Activity? :) https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/appbar/setting-up

I would really like to thank dominicoder, it indeed worked! All tutorials online didnt show it so to anyone who has the same problem, thats the solution, but theres still the problem with the icons not showing near the text(yes i tried showAsAction never/withText) i dont really know what else to do so thanks to anyone who knows:)

I'd suggest you create a new question with a  clear explanation of your problem.

After some research I would like to thank dominicoder for his initial answer, so to anyone with the same problems, this is what you should do to solve it:
First go to AndroidManifest and change android theme - android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
then in MainActivity put those in onCreate:
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
 }

and to show the icons you put in the menu.xml you would need to paste a line into onCreateOptionsMenu and when you get the error suppress it, should look something like this and the end:
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    if (menu instanceof MenuBuilder) {
        ((MenuBuilder) menu).setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

hope that helps)
